# Как сделать повторение CSS анимации через определенный промежуток времени?

Tags: css, css3

Есть CSS анимация:

```
-webkit-animation: 0.1s tremor 1s ease-out infinite;
```

Как можно задать выполнение анимации в течение 1 секунды,
и повторять через каждые 5 секунд?

Анимация:

```
@-webkit-keyframes tremor {
    0%, 25% {
        left: -1px;
        top:-1px;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-4%);
        transform: translateX(-4%);
    }
    50%, 100% {
        left: 1px;
        top: 1px;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(4%);
        transform: translateX(4%);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, анимацию надо писать ещё и без префикса. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Во-вторых, явно задать задержку между повторами нельзя. Но её можно включить в сами кадры.

```
// Сейчас у тебя что-то такое:
0%      { color: red;   }   /* начало */
100%    { color: green; }   /* 1s */

// Можно сделать так:
0%      { color: red;   }   /* начало */
16.777% { color: green; }   /* 1s */
100%    { color: green; }   /* 6s */
```

Comment: Начёт без префиксов, я просто пример скинул. Так она присутствует в коде. У меня элемент, который анимированный, трясётся. Приложил код в вопросе. Но как прописать ваш вариант, я не могу понять.